# ParseXML Data fields with Attributes using PHP cURL from API Result

Tags: php, arrays, xml, curl, php-curl

This might be quite usual for some of you but I'm not familiar with XML Data Parsing using PHP as you might be!

***Situation***

> My client's company (e-Commerce) has a tie-up with a Logistics Company which has
>   its own API for tracking shipments/packages. Now my client wants to
>   automate the Tracking for all packages they ship for their orders
>   using API Integration with the credentials provided by the Logistics
>   Company.

We have been provided the link to access the Live API, which responds data in XML format. I have already worked out with XML Responses/Data of the following type -

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ShipmentData>
<Shipment>
<Origin>New Delhi (110001)</Origin>
<Status>
<Status>Pending</Status>
<StatusLocation>Ahmedabad(Gujarat)</StatusLocation>
<StatusDateTime>2017-06-13T09:53:28.063000</StatusDateTime>
<RecievedBy/>
<Instructions>Reattempt - As per NDR instructions</Instructions>
<StatusType>UD</StatusType>
</Status>
</Shipment>
</ShipmentData>
```

*For my convenience & understanding I have tagged the above Result as **named** XML Fields, as every row is named individually*

But the result which is receive from this new Logistics Company is different as it has ***attributes*** like **name, type** which are a part of every row.

XML Response as below -

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<bd-objects version="1.0">
<object pk="1" model="awb">
<field type="BigIntegerField" name="awb_number">120420921</field>
<field type="CharField" name="orderid">123456</field>
<field type="FloatField" name="actual_weight">0.5</field>
<field type="CharField" name="origin">DELHI - DLU</field>
<field type="CharField" name="destination">BANGALORE - BAN</field>
<field type="CharField" name="current_location_name">DELHI - DEP</field>
<field type="CharField" name="current_location_code">DEP</field>
<field type="CharField" name="customer">ABC TRADING COMPANY</field>
<field type="CharField" name="consignee">John Doe</field>
<field type="CharField" name="pickupdate">13-Jun-2017</field>
<field type="CharField" name="status">Bagging completed</field>
<field type="CharField" name="tracking_status">Connected</field>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code"/>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code_description"/>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number">001</field>
<field type="CharField" name="receiver"/>
<field type="CharField" name="expected_date">20-Jun-2017</field>
<field type="CharField" name="last_update_date">18-Jun-2017</field>
<field type="CharField" name="delivery_date"/>
<field type="CharField" name="ref_awb">None</field>
<field type="CharField" name="rts_shipment">0</field>
<field type="CharField" name="system_delivery_update"/>
<field type="CharField" name="rts_system_delivery_status"/>
<field type="CharField" name="rts_reason_code_number"/>
<field type="CharField" name="rts_last_update"/>
<field type="CharField" name="pincode">560001</field>
<field type="CharField" name="city">BANGALORE</field>
<field type="CharField" name="state">Karnataka</field>
<field name="scans">...</field>
</object>
</bd-objects>
```

Now I want each of the following **named** fields like **awb_number,orderid,origin,consignee** to be stored in different variable like **$awb_number , $orderid, $origin , $consignee** so that I can make use of it for my further processing code which updates the status of the shipment on request from the server.

For the **named** field XML response I used the following code -

```
$url= "https://track.bd.com/api/packages/xml/?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=xml&output=xml&waybill="."$awb";
$dh = curl_init();
curl_setopt($dh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($dh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  //Get the URL Contents

$data = curl_exec ($dh); // Execute Curl Request


$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);


foreach ($xml -> Shipment as $row) {

$status_type = $row ->  StatusType;
$PickUpDate = $row -> PickUpDate;
$Destination = $row -> Destination;
$PickDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($PickUpDate));
$PickedDate = date("d M Y",strtotime($PickUpDate));
$ReferenceNo = $row -> ReferenceNo;
$DispatchCount = $row -> DispatchCount;
$OrderType = $row -> OrderType;

}

foreach ($xml -> Shipment->Status as $row) {

$status = $row -> Status;
$status_type = $row ->  StatusType;

$Instructions = $row -> Instructions;
$status_time = $row -> StatusDateTime;
$statustime = date("j M Y",strtotime($status_time));
}
foreach ($xml -> Shipment->Consignee as $row) {

$Name = $row -> Name;
$PinCode = $row ->  PinCode;
$Telephone1 = $row -> Telephone1;
$Address1 = $row -> Address1;
$ReverseInTransit = $row -> ReverseInTransit;
$ReturnedDate = $row -> ReturnedDate;
}
curl_close($dh);
```

*The above code worked like a charm as the fields are **named** but in the second result set I'm unable to figure out as to what code should be used to store result values from XML to PHP Variables.*

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument to the rescue!

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML(getXML()); // PS,. if its strict xml, you should probably replace loadHTML with loadXML
foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("object")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("field") as $field){
    $name=$field->getAttribute("name");
    $type=$field->getAttribute("type");
    $text=$field->textContent;
    echo 'name: '.$name.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'type: '.$type.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'text: '.$text.PHP_EOL;
}    
function getXML():string{
    $xml=<<<'XML'
<bd-objects version="1.0">
<object pk="1" model="awb">
<field type="BigIntegerField" name="awb_number">120420921</field>
<field type="CharField" name="orderid">123456</field>
<field type="FloatField" name="actual_weight">0.5</field>
<field type="CharField" name="origin">DELHI - DLU</field>
<field type="CharField" name="destination">BANGALORE - BAN</field>
<field type="CharField" name="current_location_name">DELHI - DEP</field>
<field type="CharField" name="current_location_code">DEP</field>
<field type="CharField" name="customer">ABC TRADING COMPANY</field>
<field type="CharField" name="consignee">John Doe</field>
<field type="CharField" name="pickupdate">13-Jun-2017</field>
<field type="CharField" name="status">Bagging completed</field>
<field type="CharField" name="tracking_status">Connected</field>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code"/>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code_description"/>
<field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number">001</field>
<field type="CharField" name="receiver"/>
<field type="CharField" name="expected_date">20-Jun-2017</field>
<field type="CharField" name="last_update_date">18-Jun-2017</field>
<field type="CharField" name="delivery_date"/>
<field type="CharField" name="ref_awb">None</field>
<field type="CharField" name="rts_shipment">0</field>
<field type="CharField" name="system_delivery_update"/>
<field type="CharField" name="rts_system_delivery_status"/>
<field type="CharField" name="rts_reason_code_number"/>
<field type="CharField" name="rts_last_update"/>
<field type="CharField" name="pincode">560001</field>
<field type="CharField" name="city">BANGALORE</field>
<field type="CharField" name="state">Karnataka</field>
<field name="scans">...</field>
</object>
</bd-objects>
XML;
return $xml;
}
```

output:

```
name: awb_number
type: BigIntegerField
text: 120420921
name: orderid
type: CharField
text: 123456
name: actual_weight
type: FloatField
text: 0.5
name: origin
type: CharField
text: DELHI - DLU
name: destination
type: CharField
text: BANGALORE - BAN
name: current_location_name
type: CharField
text: DELHI - DEP
name: current_location_code
type: CharField
text: DEP
name: customer
type: CharField
text: ABC TRADING COMPANY
name: consignee
type: CharField
text: John Doe
name: pickupdate
type: CharField
text: 13-Jun-2017
name: status
type: CharField
text: Bagging completed
name: tracking_status
type: CharField
text: Connected
name: reason_code
type: CharField
text: 
name: reason_code_description
type: CharField
text: 
name: reason_code_number
type: CharField
text: 001
name: receiver
type: CharField
text: 
name: expected_date
type: CharField
text: 20-Jun-2017
name: last_update_date
type: CharField
text: 18-Jun-2017
name: delivery_date
type: CharField
text: 
name: ref_awb
type: CharField
text: None
name: rts_shipment
type: CharField
text: 0
name: system_delivery_update
type: CharField
text: 
name: rts_system_delivery_status
type: CharField
text: 
name: rts_reason_code_number
type: CharField
text: 
name: rts_last_update
type: CharField
text: 
name: pincode
type: CharField
text: 560001
name: city
type: CharField
text: BANGALORE
name: state
type: CharField
text: Karnataka
name: scans
type: 
text: ...
```